# Nonlinear interpolation using Newtons method

Tags: matlab, interpolation, numerical-methods, newtons-method

Given a set of datapoints I'm trying to approximate the coefficients a,b in the function U(x)=8-ax^b using Newtons method in MATLAB.

```
x = [150 200 300 500 1000 2000]';
y = [2 3 4 5 6 7]';
a=170; b=-0.7; iter = 0; 
for iter=1:5
    f=8-a*x.^(b) -y;
    J = [-x.^b -a*b*x.^(b-1)]; %Jacobis matrix
    h=J\f;
    a=a-h(1); b=b-h(2);
    disp(norm(f))
    iter = iter+1;
end
```

The results are incorrect and I've not been sucessful of finding the misstep. All help is appreciated.

Comment: This will **not interpolate** the points (i.e. the resulting curve will not pass through the given points). It will approximate the closest curve to these points (minimize the difference between the curve and the given points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **jacobi matrix** is **wrong**. Using Newton's method, you're trying to find the values of `a` and `b`that would solve the equations `8-ax^b - y = 0`. So, your Jacobi should be the derivatives of `f` with respect to `a` and `b`. That is `J = [df/da  df/db]`, resulting in:

```
J = [-x.^b -a.*x.^b.*log(x)]
```

and you will get the following curve for the 5 iterations:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can easily linearize your model with

```
Log(8 - U(x)) = Log(a) + b Log(x)
```